# ¿Como configurar widget Frame en Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Llevo casi una semana aprendiendo a crear Gui en python con Tkinter. A la hora de crear espacio libre alrededor o crear un cuadro y determinarle las medidas del widget con usando el contenedor `Frame` no puede modificar los atributos como `padding`, `borderwidht` o `widht`.

Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()

mainframe=ttk.Frame(root, ).grid()
mainframe['padding']=(5,10)#esta linea es la que me genera problemas y es de igual forma si quiero usar borderwidht o widht
etiqueta=ttk.Label(root,text="try").grid(row=0, column=2)
buton=ttk.Button(mainframe,text="push here",command=root.quit).grid(row=1, column=24)

root.mainloop()
```

y el resultado es :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/wonder/PycharmProjects/untitled/ensayos tkinter.py", line 8, in <module>
>      mainframe['padding']=(5,10)
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error muy común en Tkinter. El problema es el uso de `grid`, `place` o `pack` en la misma linea donde se instancia el widget. Esta muy bién eso de ahorrar líneas pero a veces tiene sus consecuencias ツ.

Si se hace esto:

```
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, ).grid()
```

`mainframe` no es un objeto `ttk.Frame`, es el retorno del método `grid`, que no retorna nada (`None`). Por eso el error dice:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Si se desea usar el nombre del objeto para cambiar sus atributos posteriormente es necesario separar la instancia de la llamada del método `grid`:

```
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid()
```

Puedes ver la diferencia haciendo algo tan simple como imprimir la variable mainframe en ambos casos:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

mainframe0 = ttk.Frame(root).grid()
print(type(mainframe0))

mainframe1 = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe1.grid()
print(type(mainframe1))
```

En la salida vemos la diferencia:

```
>>> <class 'NoneType'>
>>> <class 'tkinter.ttk.Frame'>
```

Exactamente el mismo problema hay cuando se intenta encadenar la llamada a métodos del widget:

```
Entry(...).grid(...).config(..)
```

En este caso el error y el problema es idéntico, `Entry()` crea un objeto de la clase `Entry`, luego `.grid()` llama al método `grid` del objeto, hasta aquí todo bien. Luego `.config()` intenta llamar al método `config` **de la salida de grid (`None`)** y aquí tenemos el mismo problema que antes. Para que lo anterior funcionara, cada método debería retornar una referencia al objeto al que pertenece, es decir `grid` bebedera retornar una referencia al objeto creado con `Entry()` y no `None`. La solución es la misma:

```
entry = Entry(...)
entry.grid(...)
entry.config(...)
```

Si **no necesitamos nunca más hacer referencia al widget** es correcto aplicar el método en la misma línea, pero en este caso no se debe asociar una variable a la salida ya que tendremos un montón de variables, todas asociadas a `None` y totalmente inútiles. en vez de hacer:

```
button = tk.Button().grid()
label = tk.Label().grid()
```

simplemente debemos hacer:

```
tk.Button().grid()
tk.Label().grid()
```

Por otro lado, no es un error propiamente dicho pero si una muy mala práctica que por alguna razón está muy extendida en tutoriales de Tkinter, no debes nunca importar un módulo en Python de la forma (excepto casos justificados, principalmente para fusionar dos espacios de nombres):

```
from tkinter import *
```

Tu código es sencillo y no te dará problemas en principio pero puede ocasionar muchos dolores de cabeza usando módulos complejos o en proyectos medianamente grandes. Esta forma de importación expone todos los identificadores del módulo en tu namespace actual. En principio no sabes el nombre de todas las clases, objetos o funciones que contiene el módulo por lo que puedes terminar sobrescribiendo con funciones propias en tu namespace  funciones de Tkinter o viceversa sin darte cuenta. Por otro lado, dificulta la legibilidad del código por terceros ("Explícito mejor que implícito").

La forma adecuada es usar una de estas:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame...
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
```

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid()
mainframe['padding'] = 5, 10

etiqueta = ttk.Label(root, text="try")
etiqueta.grid(row=0, column=2)

buton=ttk.Button(mainframe, text="push here", command=root.quit)
buton.grid(row=1, column=24)

root.mainloop()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Edición:**

Los parámeros `weidht` y `height` se especifican igual que el resto, con la salvedad de que si queremos evitar el ajuste automático llevado a cabo por el layout y que el widget se vea forzado a tomar esas medidas necesitamos usar conjuntamente el método:`grid_propagate()`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid()
mainframe['padding'] = 5, 10
mainframe['width'] = 100
mainframe['height'] = 100
mainframe.grid_propagate(0)

etiqueta = ttk.Label(root, text="try")
etiqueta.grid(row=0, column=2)

buton=ttk.Button(mainframe, text="push here", command=root.quit)
buton.grid(row=1, column=24)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si en todos los tutoriales aparece de la misma forma from tkinter import * muchas gracias me ha funcionado perfecto !! y ahora tengo es problemas con widht y height (_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-widht")  pero muchas gracias :)

Comment: Si lo se, pero es mala práctica al igual que `using namespace std;` en c++. en progrmas para el aprendizaje generalmente no pasa nada pero se coge la costumbre y luego llegan las sorpresas desagradables cuando progrmamos cosas más complejas. En cuanto a tu otro problema he editado la pregunta. Por cierto, según el funcionamiento de SO si una pregunta es correcta y resuelve tu problema debes [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas). De esta forma agradeces el esfuerzo y es útil a otros usuarios para ver la utilidad.Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda soy nuevo y no habia visto el boton mil gracias saludos!!!